# Nginx Config for to projects under the same server_name

Tags: symfony, nginx, vue.js

I'm currently working on a project with both Symfony and VueJS. Symfony is the front on my application, as well as the API, while VueJS is used as a back-office.

I wonder if it was possible to have both the projects under the same domain name, having a path to differentiate them.

Including that, I also want to have a one and only connexion for both the frameworks. Usually, we stay connected with session with Symfony, and OAuth token given by the Symfony API for VueJS.

For that demand, I now create a OAuth Token each time someone successfully connects to the app, and keep it into local storage, just as VueJS would have it.

But I now need the good configuration to put into nginx so they can both run under the same domain name.

Don't hesitate to tell me to provide some more information, I hope it can be done ! If not, I'm open to suggestions !

Edit:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}

location /admin {
    alias /path/admin/public/dist;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location ~ /public/dist/* {
    alias /path/admin/public/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    internal;
}
```

With this configuration, I managed to access to the VueJS part, almost all the resources are loaded (except the one wrongly called).
Once I access to my page, vueJS starts and rewrite the url to /admin/login. I can login, I can access to all the pages without problem but when I reload, nginx doesn't recognize the path anymore, and I get redirected to Symfony 404 Error.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can accomplish what you want with "location" directive.

Example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        # document root, proxy pass or whatever to vuejs.
    }

    location /api {
        # document root, proxy pass or whatever to symfony.
    }
}
```

Comment: I already got to this point, so I figured I would add some information, to have a better perspective at what my issue is.